# How can i send mail form submittion in Django

Tags: django, sendmail

I want to send the data I added to the table as an e-mail at the same time, how can I do this? When i put the "send_mail(adsoyad, aciklama, alinanaksiyon, ['admin@example.com'])" after try methot in view its getting error with definitions.

views;

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def gcreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        gmember = gunluk(
            adsoyad=request.POST['adsoyad'],
            adsoyad2=request.POST['adsoyad2'],
            vardiya=request.POST['vardiya'],
            aciklama=request.POST['aciklama'],
            incident=request.POST['incident'],
            alinanaksiyon=request.POST['alinanaksiyon'],
            ulasilmayanekip=request.POST['ulasilmayanekip'],
            ulasilmayanbilgisi=request.POST['ulasilmayanbilgisi'],)
        try:
            gmember.full_clean()
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
        except ValidationError as e:
            pass
        gmember.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Ekleme İşlemi Başarılı!')
        return redirect('/gunlukistakibi')
    else:
        return render(request, 'gcreate.html')
```

settings.py;

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'XX'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'XX'
```

Comment: Does your code match the question? Are you passing `subject` or `adsoyad` as the first argument to `send_mail`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot send the e-mail becouse you have to accept the low level security from gmail account.
Go into your gmail account settings, security, then scroll down and when you find "access to low security app" or something similar, turn it on
then your email shall work